# Quiver from a single matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I have a matrix (In Matlab) which I need to plot with a quiver plot but I don't know how to turn it into a "quiver plot-able form". Are there any commands to change it? I saw some example on MathWorks Homepage using the peaks function but I couldn't get it to work.

The matrix I have is pretty huge with lots of NaN's so I created an smaller version of it.

```
Temperature = [ 1 2 2 2   3   4 6 7 ;
                1 2 3 4   4   5 6 7 ;
                2 3 4 NaN NaN 6 8 9 ;
                3 4 5 NaN NaN 7 8 9 ;
                4 4 6 6   7   8 10 11;
                4 5 7 7   8   9 11 12];
contour(Temperature)

%quiver(Temperature)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments you find the example code from the documentation which I used. Besides knowing that the dimensions are ordered [Y,X,Z] to get a matching meshgrid it's mostly copy&paste

```
% figure
figure
% [X,Y] = meshgrid(-2:.2:2);
Temperature = [ 1 2 2 2   3   4 6 7 ;
                1 2 3 4   4   5 6 7 ;
                2 3 4 NaN NaN 6 8 9 ;
                3 4 5 NaN NaN 7 8 9 ;
                4 4 6 6   7   8 10 11;
                4 5 7 7   8   9 11 12];
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:size(Temperature,2),1:size(Temperature,1));
% Z = X.*exp(-X.^2 - Y.^2);
Z=Temperature;
% [DX,DY] = gradient(Z,.2,.2);
[DX,DY] = gradient(Z,1,1);
% contour(X,Y,Z)
contour(X,Y,Z)
% hold on
hold on
% quiver(X,Y,DX,DY)
quiverscaling=3;
quiver(X,Y,DX,DY,quiverscaling)
% colormap hsv
colormap hsv
% hold off
hold off
```

Comment: Thanks. That just splendid. But there is one other thing I would like to change. As my matrix is 1000x1000 the quivers are really really small. Do you know how to get them fewer and bigger?

Comment: My last comment was wrong, seems quiver is normalizing the arrow length. I don't know a solution to have larger arrows.

Comment: Thanks... I tried that. By it seems like DX and DY is just relative sizes. If I multiply them both with 100 the plot looks the same if I multiply them both with 10000. But If I one of them are bigger it stretches in that direction.

Comment: @bjartmar: I mixed up matlab's quiver with another quiver implementation. Now the answer includes scaling by a factor of 3.